# How do you get rid of a random "pressed" class popping up on <div> click?

Tags: javascript, html, css, phonegap-build, phonegap-desktop-app

I currently have a div that I am trying to make into a like button that when clicked it switches to another image and back again when clicked again.....

With that I am having a problem where every time I click the div image it adds a class called "pressed" and the 2nd image only stays until I lift my finger off of the left-click.

I am using phonegap and and Intel mobile framework to help with the html, css, and javascript.

Is there anyway to disable this function from popping up on click or is there anything I can do to make the 2 images swap on click with a much easier method?

Thanks for the help. I am a little new at this.

HTML

```
<td align="right">
   <div class="like_button"></div>
</td>
```

CSS

```
    .like_button {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: transparent;
    border:0px;
    background-image: url(../img/like_button.png);
    background-size: 52px 52px;
    height: 52px;
    width: 52px;
}

    .like_button:active {
    background-image: url(../img/liked_button.png);
    background-size: 52px 52px;
    height: 52px;
    width: 52px;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
jQuery('like_button').click(function(){
   jQuery(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

Comment: When I change it to .active the 2nd image does not show up anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like what *lmgonzalves* said in the comments, I think the problem has to do with the `:active` pseudo selector which is mostly used to alter an element's state while it is being activated (being clicked on or otherwise activated), hence the split second effect you are experiencing when you lift your finger away.

Instead, you should remove the pseudo selector and use a simple class selector like `.like_button.clicked` in handling state changes CSS.

You can see the demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/k135g025/

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think we are 95% there! This is working well, the only thing is the button keeps reloading the entire page every time I click it. Any fixes for that?

Comment: Great~ Make sure the button does not have any <a href> links, otherwise I don't see why this would trigger a page reload based on your current codes.

Comment: Figured it out, you have to add type="button" and it works perfecty! Thanks for the help! <button class="like_button" type="button"></button>

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `.like_button:active` to `.like_button.active` in your CSS.

And also `jQuery('like_button')` should be `jQuery('.like_button')` in jQuery code.

Comment: I did both of those changes but now the 2nd image does not show up at all. The "pressed" class shows up only when I press down on the div but when I let go the "pressed" class goes away.  Could that be a problem?

Comment: See [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/zbnswxde/), I put the word "LIKE" inside `div.like_button`, and `color: red;` in `.like_button.active` to show the difference. Let me know how it work for you ;)

Comment: Maybe it's because you are talking about class "pressed", but in your code the class is named "active".

Comment: It works in the jsfiddle but not on my site even when I copy it exactly over. This is the code I that it brings up when I push down on the button only.{ <div class="like_button pressed">LIKE</div> }